# How to pause/play multiple MediaPlayer objects with one button?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I have a button and i want to control multiple MediaPlayer objects with that button. **In example the user choosed 3 sound from the list and when they are playing user clicked to the pause icon button and all the sounds should pause (and pause button's resource should change to play icon). If user clicks again to the play icon all the sounds should keep going on.**

If i delete the else part in my code i can achieve that pausing sounds which is playing currently but if i click again to the play button sounds won't play and nothing happens.

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stop_all_sound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/pause_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My code:

```
    stop_all_sound.setOnClickListener {
        // List of sounds
        val list = arrayListOf(sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4)
        // List for playing sounds
        val playingSounds = arrayListOf<MediaPlayer>()

        list.forEach { sound ->
            if (sound.isPlaying) {
                // If sound is playing add it to the playingSounds list
                playingSounds.add(sound)

                for (playingSound in playingSounds) {
                    // Pause that playing sounds currently
                    playingSound.pause()
                    stop_all_sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button)
                }
            }
            // I couldn't figured out this part. I guess playingSounds list is empty
            else {
                for (playingSound in playingSounds) {
                    playingSound.start()
                    stop_all_sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### Update

To make it more clear, let's say there is a List of `MediaPlayer` and a `Button`

- If no `MediaPlayer` is in playing state, the icon of the `Button` will be *play_button,* otherwise *pause_button*

I want the following behavior of the `MediaPlayer`s when the `Button` is pressed:

- If **no** MediaPlayer is playing and **no** MediaPlayer is in pause state, all the MediaPlayer will start playing
- If **no** MediaPlayer is playing and **some** MediaPlayer is in pause state, all the paused MediaPlayer will start playing
- If **some** MediaPlayer is playing and **no** MediaPlayer is in pause state, all the playing MediaPlayer will be paused

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

```
var buttonIcon: Int = R.drawable.play_button

val playList = PlayList { isPlaying ->
    buttonIcon =
        if (isPlaying) R.drawable.pause_button
        else R.drawable.play_button
    stop_all_sound.setImageResource(buttonIcon)
}

stop_all_sound.setOnClickListener {
    // List of sounds
    val list = arrayListOf(sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4)
    if (playList.isEmpty()) {
        buttonIcon = R.drawable.play_button
        list.forEach { sound ->
            if (sound.isPlaying) {
                playList.add(sound)
                buttonIcon = R.drawable.pause_button
            }
        }
        if (playList.isEmpty()) list.forEach { playList.add(it) }
    }
    when (buttonIcon) {
        R.drawable.play_button -> playList.play()
        R.drawable.pause_button -> playList.pause()
    }
}

// PlayList class

class PlayList(private val playingState: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    private val soundList = mutableListOf<MediaPlayer>()

    fun isEmpty() = soundList.isEmpty()

    fun add(sound: MediaPlayer) {
        sound.setOnCompletionListener {
            soundList.remove(it)
            if (soundList.isEmpty()) playingState(false)
        }
        soundList.add(sound)
    }

    fun play() {
        soundList.forEach {
            it.start()
        }
        playingState(true)
    }

    fun pause() {
        soundList.forEach {
            if (it.isPlaying) it.pause()
        }
        playingState(false)
    }
}
```

### Initial Answer

I can figure out the following test cases from your question,

1. User chooses a list of songs
2. User presses the Play/Pause button to play all the chosen songs if no song is playing
3. User presses the Play/Pause button to stop all the songs that are currently playing

In the above cases, I would probably do the following:

```
var buttonIcon = R.drawable.play_button

val playList = PlayList(arrayListOf(sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4)) { isPlaying ->
    if (isPlaying) {
        buttonIcon = R.drawable.pause_button
        stop_all_sound.setImageResource(buttonIcon)
    } else {
        buttonIcon = R.drawable.play_button
        stop_all_sound.setImageResource(buttonIcon)
    }
}

stop_all_sound.setOnClickListener {
    when(buttonIcon) {
        R.drawable.play_button -> playList.play()
        R.drawable.pause_button -> playList.pause()
    }
}
```

The `PlayList` class

```
class PlayList(
    private val soundList: List<MediaPlayer>,
    private val playingState: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    private var nowPlayingCount = 0

    init {
        soundList.forEach {
            it.setOnCompletionListener {
                nowPlayingCount = nowPlayingCount.dec()
                if (nowPlayingCount == 0) playingState(false)
            }
        }
    }

    fun play() {
        soundList.forEach {
            it.start()
        }
        playingState(true)
        nowPlayingCount = soundList.size
    }

    fun pause() {
        soundList.forEach {
            if (it.isPlaying) it.pause()
        }
        playingState(false)
        nowPlayingCount = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Every case is true except second one because when the user chooses a song from list it will be playing already. As i said in the above i want to pause the sounds which is playing currently if the user click pause button and then pause button gonna change to the play button. If user clicks again to that play button all paused songs should keep going on.

Comment: I tried your code above and it pauses the sounds which is playing but it is playing sounds which is not playing.